# Why does Javascript calculate this equation differently than my calculator?

Tags: javascript

If I do this equation in Firebase functions (in JavaScript):

```
var q = 0.1
var alpha = 0.1
var gamma = 0.99
var max5 = 0

q = (1 - alpha) * q + (alpha * (-1 + (gamma * max5)));

console.log(q)
```

the result is -0.009999999999999995

But if I do this equation on a calculator it is -0.01

I should note, I pasted a simplified version of the code above, but all the variables get the parseFloat operation, so I'm sure it has something to do with that.  Or is it something else?

Comment: It is likely due to slight differences in internal precision - standard floating point has a _relative precision_. Search for "is floating point math broken" or "IEEE-754" float to see lots of details on the subject and how floating point numbers are stored. JavaScript uses IEEE-754 64-bit Binary (which can internally be processed as 80-bit in x86 FPUs..). That specific calculation? No clue.. it could also be that the calculator uses a different rounding method on display.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a weird way javascript handles floating point numbers. (You can read more [here](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/))

For example, if you do this in firebase or just the console in the browser

```js
console.log(0.1 + 0.2);
// 0.30000000000000004
```

This is just a JavaScript wide thing. The way to get around it is to call `.toFixed(2)`. This will round the number to 2 decimal places.

```js
console.log(+(0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(2));
// 0.3
```

(In case you are wondering why the `+` is in there before the numbers, it's because `.toFixed()` returns a string. The `+` turns it back into a number)